# mdadm RAID0 array recovery

Tags: linux, raid, mdadm

I have a Linux file server with two 12-disk MD1000 disk arrays attached to a RAID controller. Unfortunately, a power blip has caused a loss of configuration data on the RAID controller and it is now reporting no disk configuration. I have no backup or record of the original configuration.

Looking at the server log from the last time it successfully booted, it uses mdadm to construct a RAID0 array of 4 devices (although there is no mdadm.conf file anywhere, so i guess it autodetects) and each device is a hardware RAID5 array.

To try to recover the configuration and data: I did a dd of each disks and used the ReclaiMe (Windows) tool to establish that the original configuration was RAID50 with 4 hardware RAID5 arrays (combined using mdadm) -- plus 4 spares.

ReclaiMe has also recovered images of the 4 RAID5 arrays (into files labelled 1.img, 2.img, 3.img, 4.img) and specified the following config information for the RAID0 construction:

> 11. On the right side of the R-Studio window, set "RAID type" to "RAID0 (Stripe set)".
> 12. Below that, set "Block size" to "256 KB".
> 13. In the "Parents" table, enter "63 Sectors" as "Offset" in all rows.

I have used R-studio with these parameters to verify the data is there and I am now trying to assemble the RAID0 array using mdadm so I can mount the original filesystem. It is at this point that I am slightly stuck. I have mounted the (NTFS-formatted) physical disks containing the images (1 physical disk per image) and then mounted the images themselves as loop devices:

```
# losetup /dev/loop1 /media/ubuntu/disk1/1.img
# losetup /dev/loop2 /media/ubuntu/disk2/2.img
# losetup /dev/loop3 /media/ubuntu/disk3/3.img
# losetup /dev/loop4 /media/ubuntu/disk4/4.img
```

Running an fdisk on an loop device:

```
# fdisk -l /dev/loop2
Disk /dev/loop2: 2000.4 GB, 2000435544064 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243205 cylinders, total 3907100672 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

  Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/loop2p1              63  3902798969  1951399453+  fd  Linux raid autodetect
```

When I try to automatically assemble,I get:

```
# mdadm --assemble --scan -v
mdadm: Cannot assemble mbr metadata on /dev/loop4
mdadm: Cannot assemble mbr metadata on /dev/loop3
mdadm: Cannot assemble mbr metadata on /dev/loop2
mdadm: Cannot assemble mbr metadata on /dev/loop1
```

When I try to do it manually:

```
# mdadm --create /dev/md0 -v --level=0 --assume-clean --raid-devices=4 /dev/loop1 /dev/loop2 /dev/loop3 /dev/loop4
mdadm: chunk size defaults to 512K
mdadm: /dev/loop1 appears to be part of a raid array:
level=raid0 devices=0 ctime=Thu Jan  1 00:00:00 1970
mdadm: partition table exists on /dev/loop1 but will be lost or
   meaningless after creating array
mdadm: /dev/loop2 appears to be part of a raid array:
level=raid0 devices=0 ctime=Thu Jan  1 00:00:00 1970
mdadm: partition table exists on /dev/loop2 but will be lost or
   meaningless after creating array
mdadm: /dev/loop3 appears to be part of a raid array:
level=raid0 devices=0 ctime=Thu Jan  1 00:00:00 1970
mdadm: partition table exists on /dev/loop3 but will be lost or
   meaningless after creating array
mdadm: /dev/loop4 appears to be part of a raid array:
level=raid0 devices=0 ctime=Thu Jan  1 00:00:00 1970
mdadm: partition table exists on /dev/loop4 but will be lost or
   meaningless after creating array
Continue creating array? N
```

I wondered if the offset mentioned in the ReclaiMe output and corresponding to the Start 63 in the fdisk output required different losetup, so tried instead (because 63 * 512 = 32256):

```
# losetup /dev/loop1 /media/ubuntu/disk1/1.img -o 32256
# losetup /dev/loop2 /media/ubuntu/disk2/2.img -o 32256
# losetup /dev/loop3 /media/ubuntu/disk3/3.img -o 32256
# losetup /dev/loop4 /media/ubuntu/disk4/4.img -o 32256
```

Then:

```
# mdadm --assemble --scan -v 
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/loop4
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/loop3
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/loop2
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/loop1
```

So, I tried to manually create again:

```
# mdadm --create /dev/md0 -v --level=0 --assume-clean --raid-devices=4  /dev/loop1 /dev/loop2 /dev/loop3 /dev/loop4
mdadm: chunk size defaults to 512K
mdadm: /dev/loop1 appears to contain an ext2fs file system
    size=-784337920K  mtime=Wed Dec  4 12:34:29 2013
Continue creating array? N
```

At this point, i don't know what to do. I have already had to restore the 4 img files (totalling 8TB) from a backup a couple of times by trying options that didn't work.

[Also, is there any way to ascertain the metadata version or chunk size?]

Comment: If you're able to get to the data otherwise (through the recovery software), recover the data and rebuild the array from scratch.

Comment: Umm, don't you need an --assume-clean?

Comment: I can recover some data, but i think some is missing. Also the file permissions are not recovered correctly.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I did it with --assume-clean too and the results were the same. I will edit my post to add that information.